# Average cost of an item from container with different chances

Tags: probability, expected-value, average, gambling

i need to find average cost for every item in container.
It costs **50 currency** to open one.
I have following chances for items:

- `lvl-1: 58%`
- `lvl-2: 24%`
- `lvl-3: 12%`
- `lvl-4: 6%`
- and lvl-5 is **not** included in it.

The thing is that i can get `N` lvl item by merging two `N-1` lvl items. So lvl-5 is obtainable only by merging two lvl-4 items.

What is the right way to calculate average/expected cost of each item?

Comment: You need to give more information: for example when you want a level 1 item, you may get a higher level item first.  Would that count as being of value or just a wasted $50$?

Comment: @Henry hi, my bad. Generally yes, higher lvls are more valuable. Mechanic of the game is simple, there is an order that you need to complete, and it requires multiple items of different levels. There are also different types of items, let's say gold / silver / bronze. Order may require lvl-3 gold item, lvl-4 silver item, and lvl-5 bronze item. Different types have different costs. It's an event in game, where you gain currency throughout 22 days.

Comment: So in the beginning it may do not matter what lvl item you get from container, it will be used in future, but close to end you begin to aim for specific levels to just complete the order. And if u get higher lvls only for example, and their combination doesnt allow to complete the order, then it counts as waste.

Comment: Amount of currency that is possible to gain varies from 92k to 110k+. Bronze costs 50 to open. Silver 70. Gold 100.

Comment: There are 26 combinations of items that represent different orders. I just wanted to calculate estimated progress, but got confused with how to calculate order cost. My friend came up with solution to multiple the cost of container by the chance of lvl-1 item, it will be its cost. And every next lvl is twice as expensive. But it doesn't seem right, because estimated progress then looks much less then was achieved by other players.

Comment: If you were allowed to swap either way at no cost between $k$ items at level $n$ and $2k$ items at level $n-1$, then in a sense you expect to get the equivalent of $1\times 0.58+2\times 0.24+4 \times 0.12 + 8 \times 0.06= 2.02$ level $1$ items each turn at a cost of $50$, so with an effective cost of $\frac{2500}{101}\approx 24.75$ per level $1$ item, with each higher level being double the effective cost of the previous level.

Comment: @Henry thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From comment:*

If you were allowed to swap either way at no cost between $k$ items at level $n$ and $2k$ items at level $n−1$,

then in a sense you expect to get the equivalent of $1×0.58+2×0.24+4×0.12+8×0.06=2.02$ level $1$ items each turn at a cost of $50$,

so with an effective cost of $\frac{2500}{101}\approx 24.75$ per level $1$ item,

with each higher level being double the effective cost of the previous level.